# How do I display the html page for a Custom SharePoint List view?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2016

I'm attempting to create a custom list view in a SharePoint 2016 site collection through PowerShell.

```
$viewTitle = "newview"

#add the following fields to the list
$viewFields = New - Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
$viewFields.Add("Title") > $null
$viewFields.Add("Description") > $null
$viewFields.Add("EndDate") > $null
$viewFields.Add("Priority") > $null
$viewFields.Add("EventDate") > $null
$viewFields.Add("Status") > $null

#filter query
$viewQuery = "<Where><Or><Neq><FieldRef Name='_Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>Completed</Value></Neq><Geq><FieldRef Name='DateCompleted1' /><Value Type='DateCompleted1'><Today OffsetDays='-14' /></Value></Geq></Or></Where>"

$viewDefaultView = $false
$viewPaged = $true
$viewRowLimit = 30
$viewType = "Html"

$newview = $list.Views.Add($viewTitle, $viewFields, $viewQuery, $viewRowLimit, $viewPaged, $viewDefaultView, $viewType, $false)
```

The view seems to create fine. However when I go to actually look at it, I just get a blank page. If I set the $viewType to "Grid" I can see it. When I have it as "Html" It is blank. How do I use "Html" for this view?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that your quert is correct.

In your query `<FieldRef Name='DateCompleted1' /><Value Type='DateCompleted1'><Today OffsetDays='-14' />`.

It should be like this:

```
<FieldRef Name='DateCompleted1' /><Value Type='DateTime'><Today Offset='-14' />
```

Comment: Good pick up. But this hasn't resolved my issue.